# Creating empty matrix and filling in date matched values in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm quite new to R and apologise in advance for my post not being in the usual format (I tried using `dput()` but got a weird output and have no idea how to upload datasets I'm really sorry).

I have a dataset with 6 colums (site,  startdate, enddate, photodate, species, indiv). For example:

```
site    year    startdate   enddate photodate   species indiv
M1_7    2012    19/07/2012  10/08/2012  20/07/2012  Sylvicapra grimmia  1
M1_7    2012    19/07/2012  10/08/2012  23/07/2012  Crocuta crocuta 1
M1_7    2012    19/07/2012  10/08/2012  23/07/2012  Potamochoerus larvatus  1
M1_7    2012    19/07/2012  10/08/2012  25/07/2012  Hystrix cristata    1
M1_7    2012    19/07/2012  10/08/2012  27/07/2012  Potamochoerus larvatus  1
M1_7    2012    19/07/2012  10/08/2012  27/07/2012  Sylvicapra grimmia  1
M1_7    2012    19/07/2012  10/08/2012  28/07/2012  Hippotragus equinus     1
M1_7    2012    19/07/2012  10/08/2012  30/07/2012  Crocuta crocuta 1
M1_7    2012    19/07/2012  10/08/2012  01/08/2012  Equus q. boehmi 1
M1_7    2012    19/07/2012  10/08/2012  01/08/2012  Crocuta crocuta 1
M1_7    2012    19/07/2012  10/08/2012  05/08/2012  Potamochoerus larvatus  1
M1_7    2012    19/07/2012  10/08/2012  07/08/2012  Hippotragus equinus     1
M1_9    2012    21/07/2012  11/08/2012  24/07/2012  Pedetes capensis    1
M1_9    2012    21/07/2012  11/08/2012  24/07/2012  Crocuta crocuta 2
M1_9    2012    21/07/2012  11/08/2012  24/07/2012  Pedetes capensis    1
M1_9    2012    21/07/2012  11/08/2012  27/07/2012  Pedetes capensis    1
M1_9    2012    21/07/2012  11/08/2012  01/08/2012  Alcelaphus b. lichtensteinii    1
M1_9    2012    21/07/2012  11/08/2012  03/08/2012  Pedetes capensis    1
M1_9    2012    21/07/2012  11/08/2012  04/08/2012  Crocuta crocuta 1
M1_9    2012    21/07/2012  11/08/2012  06/08/2012  Pedetes capensis    1
M1_9    2012    21/07/2012  11/08/2012  07/08/2012  Pedetes capensis    1
M1_9    2012    21/07/2012  11/08/2012  08/08/2012  Pedetes capensis    1
M1_11   2012    21/07/2012  11/08/2012  26/07/2012  Mellivora capensis  1
M1_11   2012    21/07/2012  11/08/2012  03/08/2012  Sylvicapra grimmia  1
M1_11   2012    21/07/2012  11/08/2012  07/08/2012  Hystrix cristata    1
M1_11   2012    21/07/2012  11/08/2012  08/08/2012  Potamochoerus larvatus  1
```

I've been trying to write a loop which creates a 49 column matrix where column 1 corresponds to the site, column 2 to the sequence of dates between "startdate" and "enddate" within a site, column 3:49 to species names. Within the cells under columns 3:49, I would like to fill them with the data derived from summing up the count data (indiv), for a particular species, at a particular date.

So far I have only been able to create an empty matrix corresponding to what I want, but have been unable to fill in the data. This is the code I have used:

```
mlele2012<- read.delim("C:\\multiple regression\\mlele 2012 empty matrix creation.txt")
africa <- read.delim("C:\\species accumulation curves\\COMPLETE species list.txt")
specieslistx<-unique(africa)
specieslistx<-t(specieslistx) 

oldtemp<-NULL 
temp <- rep(0, length(specieslistx ))

strptime(mlele2012$photodate, "%Y-%m-%d")
strptime(mlele2012$startdate, "%d/%m/%Y")
strptime(mlele2012$enddate, "%d/%m/%Y")

#create empty dataframe with dimensions: no. of sites x no. of dates in each

for(i in levels(mlele2012$site))    { ##for each site

    sitetemp <- subset(mlele2012, site == i) ###subset of dataset , for the particular site i##

    sitetemp$startdate<- as.Date(sitetemp$startdate, "%d/%m/%Y")
    sitetemp$enddate<- as.Date(sitetemp$enddate, "%d/%m/%Y")

    sitedatelist<-seq(as.Date(sitetemp$startdate[1]), as.Date(sitetemp$enddate[1]), "days")

    empty<-matrix(0,length(sitedatelist),length(specieslistx))
    sitedatelist1<-as.character(sitedatelist)
    row.names(empty)<-(sitedatelist1)
    colnames(empty)<-specieslistx

    addsitecol<-matrix(0,length(sitedatelist),1)
    extendempty<-cbind(addsitecol,empty)
    extendempty[,1]<-i
    oldtemp<-rbind(oldtemp, extendempty)
}

write.csv(oldtemp, "Mlele 2012 dry empty.csv")
```

In addition, I have been trying to extract to create another matrix in the same format/dimensions, but without the excess dates (i.e. only dates in the "photodate" column and not the sequence between "startdate" and "enddate"). I was hoping that I could eventually somehow merge the two matrices to get what I ultimately need. Unfortunately this code does not work, although there doesn't seem to be an error. Here's the second part of my code:

```
for(i in mlele2012$site)    {    
   sitetemp <- subset(mlele2012, site == i) ###subset of dataset "allsites", for the particular site i##
   for(j in sitetemp$photodate){
      datetemp <- subset(sitetemp, photodate == j) ###subset of dataset "africaa", for the particular date i#
      uniquespperdate <- unique(datetemp$species)###unique species within each date (row) i#
      temp <- rep(0, length(specieslistx)) #create a temporary vector of 0s with the same length as the species list###

      for(a in uniquespperdate){
         sptemp <- subset(datetemp , species == a) ###subset of dataset "sitetemp", for the particular sp j##
         countdata<-sum(sptemp$indiv)
         index <- pmatch(a, names(temp)) ###match the unique species per date to the location on the species list###
         #there is a problem here, it works when run as a single line but not within a loop
         temp[index] <- countdata   ###for the locations listed in "index", assign the count data to the temporary vector###
         names(temp)<- specieslistx
      }
   }        
   oldtemp <- rbind(oldtemp, temp) ### bind the new temp file to the old temp file, i.e. update the list as the loop runs###
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Kindly let me know if there are any details I can provide to make the question clearer.

Comment: Maybe try `dput(head(x))`? Also, the question would be more readable if all of your code was indented four spaces. Some of it is showing up outside the code blocks.

Comment: Agree with point number 1 (use `dput(.)`)  but sometimes following inexperienced R users' strategies is not going to be the most efficient approach.

Answer (score 1):

I can get most of the way there on your sample with:

```
> ftable(xtabs(indiv~site+year+species, data=dat) )
           species boehmi capensis cristata crocuta equinus grimmia larvatus lichtensteinii
site  year                                                                                 
M1_11 2012              0        1        1       0       0       1        1              0
M1_7  2012              1        0        1       3       2       2        3              0
M1_9  2012              0        7        0       3       0       0        0              1
```

I did input the data using genus/species as two columns because you did not offer the requested dput version.

Answer (score 0):

A bit messy, but without initializing an empty matrix, you could do the following:

If `df` is your initial data:

```
result = do.call("rbind",lapply(levels(df$site),function(x){
    do.call("rbind",lapply(levels(df$startdate),function(y){
        do.call("rbind",lapply(levels(df$enddate),function(z){
            foo <- rep(0,length(levels(df$species)))
            names(foo) <- levels(df$species)
            foo[df$species[df$site==x & df$startdate==y & df$enddate==z]] <- df$indiv[df$site==x & df$startdate==y & df$enddate==z]
            c(x,y,z,foo)
        }))
    }))
}))
```

`result` should contain the matrix you seek (I hope).